# Guid Parameter is always null in Controller ActionResult

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, controller

I have a controller like below:

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> MyControllerMethod(string currency = null,
                                                            string edition = null,
                                                            int? systems = null,
                                                            string version = null,
                                                            Guid? entitlementid = null)
{
//Code here
}
```

When i execute this controller from this URL:

```
http://*:*/MyController/MyControllerMethod/?currency=eur&edition=DSSTANDARD&systems=50&version=6.3/
```

All the parameters of the method have the values like below:

```
currency = eur
edition = DSSTANDARD
systems = 50
version = 6.3
```

But if i do the same adding the last parameter:

```
...&entitlementid=B5630B37-0820-4EB0-8A2A-000C44885590/
```

Then, the first 3 values have the values from URL but `entitlementid` is always `null`.
What can be the issue?

Route Config

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute( 
    name: "DefaultApi", 
    routeTemplate: "{controller}/{action}/{id}", 
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional } 
);
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16605632/mvc-querystring-with-guid-returns-404

Comment: @KartikeyaKhosla I do not have <requestLimits written at all...

Comment: This looks like a WebAPI call. Can you show the route config.

Comment: @Nkosi config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );

Comment: If you try changing `entitlementId` to a string is it still null?

Comment: If i make it string it comes with a value but i want to use it in LINQ query and when i use Guid.Parse(string) it throws error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are including an extra slash `/` at the end of the query string

```
...&entitlementid=B5630B37-0820-4EB0-8A2A-000C44885590/
```

which is causing the `Guid` binding to become invalid. If you remove the slash and make the request then the `entitlementid` will be populated.

`http://*:*/MyController/MyControllerMethod/?currency=eur&edition=DSSTANDARD&systems=50&version=6.3&entitlementid=B5630B37-0820-4EB0-8A2A-000C44885590`

Should work as expected.