# Why is MVC Area Routing not working as expected?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-areas, areas

I have the following area set up on my site.

```
public class AdminAreaRegistration : AreaRegistration
{
    public override string AreaName
    {
        get
        {
            return "Admin";
        }
    }

    public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
    {
        context.MapRoute(
            "AdminDefaultNoAction",
            "Admin/{controller}/{id}",
            new { action = "Home", id = UrlParameter.Optional }, new[] { "DevTest.Areas.Admin.Controllers" }
        );

        context.MapRoute(
            "AdminDefault",
            "Admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { action = "Home", id = UrlParameter.Optional }, new[] { "DevTest.Areas.Admin.Controllers" }
        );
    }
}
```

And the following methods in my **controller**.

```
public class PlayerController : Controller
{
    public PlayerController()
    {

    }

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Home(Guid id)
    {
        var model = new HomeViewModel();
        // Do Stuff
        return View("Home", model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Home(HomeViewModel model)
    {
        // Do Stuff
        return View("Home", model);
    }

    public ActionResult TestMethod(Guid id)
    {
        return Json(new
        {
            Test = "Hi!",
            id = id.ToString()
        });
    }
}
```

My two home methods work fine. TestMethod works if I hit it with **Admin/Player/TestMethod/e0ef4ab3-3fe5-4ea8-8ae1-c16b9defcabe**" but fails if I hit it with **Admin/Player/TestMethod?id=e0ef4ab3-3fe5-4ea8-8ae1-c16b9defcabe**.

This is obviously just a demonstrative example. I want to be able to hit some methods in this Controller passing values in (mostly via ajax requests) but the routing is not working as intended.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try setting `maxQueryString` parameter in web.config file to larger limit or get rid of it, see this similar issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16605632/mvc-querystring-with-guid-returns-404.

Comment: Your routes do not really make sense. The first one matches any url with `Admin` followed by one or 2 segments, so `Admin/Player/TestMethod?id=e0ef4ab3-3fe5-4ea8-8ae1-c16b9defcabe` ,matches it and goes to the `Home()` method of `PlayerController` and passes "TestMethod" to the `id` parameter

Comment: Just delete your first route (its not clear what its for) or add a constraint to the `{id}` segment to ensure its a `Guid`

Comment: @Stephen Muecke I deleted the first route, as you said and that did fix this. However, I now cannot do a request like "Admin/Player/[guid]" and have it route to my specified default action. How can I setup my Area Route config to achieve both? TIA

Comment: You can add a route constraint (so that if its not a `Guid` it does not match the `AdminDefaultNoAction` route and falls through to the `AdminDefault` route

Comment: For an example, refer [these answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2421995/how-can-i-create-a-route-constraint-of-type-system-guid)

Comment: @Stephen Muecke Had to google how to do that, but it's working for both now. Thank you.

Comment: Your routing is misconfigured. See [Why map special routes first before common routes in asp.net mvc?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35674633/181087)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted by @Stephen Muecke in the comments, my first route was not specific enough. I had to constrain the id to be a guid for it to work as intended.

I did this with a regex as I'm still using Mvc version 4.

```
context.MapRoute(
    "AdminDefaultNoAction",
    "Admin/{controller}/{id}",
    new { action = "Home", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
    new { id = @"[a-f0-9-]+" },
    new[] { "DevTest.Areas.Admin.Controllers" }
);
```

If I had Mvc 5 I could have used:

```
new { guid = new GuidRouteConstraint() }
```